# Page scrolls upwards when I click on a link

Tags: html

I have a html page that has a scrollbar (default scrollbar) & I have a small form at the bottom of the page.

Now the problem is when I scroll down & click on **Select/List menu** to select any option from the form, the scrollbar shifts up. Why is this happening? I can still select the options as the page is not very long. Why does the scrollbar go up? Can somebody help me with this?

I read that sometimes # link can be the reason, I tried removing it, but still the same. Also there is **"onfocus=...** in my page, I tried removing that & tested it but it still goes up.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code for form.

```
<div class="bottom-form">
<form action="#" method="post">

<div class="main-inp-box">
<div class="inp-box">
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" class="field1" placeholder="Enter your first name" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter your first name';" onfocus="if(this.value=='*Enter your first name:') this.value='';"/>
  </label>
</div>


<div class="inp-box">  
<label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" class="field1" placeholder="Your email id here" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your email id here ';" onfocus="if(this.value=='*Your email id here:') this.value='';"/>
  </label>
</div>


<div class="inp-box" style="margin-right:0">
<dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
        <dt><a href="#"><span style="color:#dad9d9; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; ">Select your role</span></a></dt>
        <dd>

            <ul>
            <div class="head2"><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong></div>
                <li><a href="#">Option1<span class="value">xx</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Option2<span class="value">yy</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option3<span class="value">yy</span></a></li>
            </ul>

        </dd>
       </dl>
</div>

</div>

<div class="main">
<div class="notify_btn_box"><a href="#" class="red-btn"></a></div>
<div class="arrow"><img src="images/arrow.png" /></div>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:100px;"><span class="text-note">*we have no spam policy</span></div>

</form>
</div>
```

Here's the updated code. with # removed

```
<div class="inp-box" style="margin-right:0">
<dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
        <dt><a href=""><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; color:#909090; ">Select your role</span></a></dt>
        <dd>

            <ul>
            <div class="head2"><strong>Who are you?</strong></div>

                <li><a href="">Option1<span class="value">xx</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="">Option2<span class="value">yy</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="">Option3<span class="value">yy</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: Sure, sorry m new here. How do i post the code.

Comment: An easy way to share html code is by putting it on http://jsfiddle.net/ and sharing the link here. Alternatively, just paste the code into your question using "code" formatting (there's a button on the edit toolbar to mark content as code)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `<dl>` tag as though it's a dropdown list, but it's really a [definition list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp). Dropdowns are created using the [`<select>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) tag, and once you fix that, you'll no longer need the `<a href="#">` items (which are causing the scrolling).

Comment: Hey sorry the proj was on hold for some time. Will try this. Thanks so much for ur help.